# how to deploy managed package in salesforce

Tags: package, deployment, tools, managed-package

I am trying to deploy survey force app using changeset from one sandbox to another but it is throwing an error that managed package can not be moved using change sets. What is the best approach to move it from  sandbox to sandbox and sandbox to prod.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the ANT based [Force.com Migration Tool](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Migration_Tool_Guide) to automate installing the required packages. In particular, look at `<installPackage>`.

```
<project name="installdemo" default="build" basedir=".">
    <!-- Load standard properties -->
    <property file="${basedir}/build.properties"/>    
    <!-- Import macros around sf:deploy to install/uninstall packages -->
    <import file="${basedir}/lib/ant-salesforce.xml"/>
    <!-- Default target -->  
    <target name="build">     
        <!-- Install the package with namespace packagea -->
        <installPackage namespace="packagea" version="1.0" packagePassword="fred1234"
           username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}"/>
        <!-- Uninstall the package with namespace pacakgea -->
        <uninstallPackage namespace="packagea"
           username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}"/>     
    </target> 
</project>
```

That example is from Andrew Fawcett's blog post - [“Look ma, no hands!” : Automating Install and Uninstall of Packages!](https://andyinthecloud.com/2013/06/23/look-ma-no-hands-automating-install-and-uninstall-of-packages/). That post also includes an example of installing packages from Apex via the Metadata API.

Answer (score 0):

As managed packages are black box of functionality/features which can not be customized(as in unmanaged packages), it would be best to install them separately on different organizations(sandboxes/dev/production instances).

Comment: you mean I had to deploy in each sandbox  like Dev, Qa, UAT and Prod. It is too much of doing repeated task tight?, I expected the ANT tool may help in deploying the Managed Packages.